# In the (American) Power Rangers franchise, who built/constructed the first Zords?

Tags: power-rangers, zordon

I know it seems like an odd question, considering the original Rangers' master, Zordon of El'tar, was seen as the originator of the Power Ranger legacy.... heck *"Zord"* is even in his *name,* and that suffix exist on **every iteration** of the Rangers' fighting machines TO THIS DAY.

And we *have* seen Zordon and his robotic assistant, Alpha 5, create new Zords... or at the very least, they have the combination of super power and technology to *upgrade* existing Zords, arguably on a molecular level if the "morphing lightning" and the vastly different abilities are any indication...

This is where things get confusing...

Now, when the third season of *Mighty Morphin Power Rangers* began, a lot of shifts took place. Story wise, Lord Zedd had long destroyed the Dinozords with his Pirantushead monster in season 2, which facilitated the need to reformat them into the Thunderzords. If memory serves, by season 3 the Thunderzords were *completely* destroyed, so couldn't be "retooled"; this forced the Rangers to seek out Ninjor, a humanoid warrior entity and ally of Zordon. This is where things get more murky, as *Ninjor* was now touted in-story to be the *original creator* of the Power Coins; he gives the team new Ninja Coins, providing them with the even "more powerful" Ninjazords.

There are a few inconsistencies now which bring true Zord creation into question.

Now practically speaking, the original *Dai Ranger*  Japanese series the Zord footage was edited from had long since wrapped, and as such, no more Dinozord battle scenes were being made; in truth, an **entirely new Team of Rangers** were in use in Japan, and it was *that* Ranger show the Thunderzord footage was being pulled from. A similar switch over was needed for the new "Ninja themed" season in Japan, facilitating the introduction of Ninjazords and Ninja powers in the American show.

But the "real world" series bungles the contradictions to the shows own history, as we **see** Zordon and Alpha *literally create* the White Ranger's coin and powers (**including** the Tigerzord) in Season 2. Season 3, however, implies that *Ninjor* created the original coins, and thus the Dinozords attached to them. While, to the series credit, it was never outright *stated* Zordon himself "made" the Zords, it *was* heavily implied....**especially** through the naming!

What's more, the Zordon-origin is sort of supported in both the 1995 and 2017 films. Granted, it's more of a *circumstantial* evidence in **MMPR:TM,** and that film isn't exactly treated as "Canon", but it's fundamentally the *same* universe. In the 1995 film, the Omega-Level villain Ivan Ooze swears to "obliterate his (Zordon's) entire *legacy!*"  and when Zordon *himself* is injured by Ivan, everything attached to him or created by him was shattered.

In Zordon's own words:

> The Power has been destroyed. It is *gone* ...the Zords...the weapons... All of it. The Power Rangers are no more.

So if Zordon didn't *originate* the coins or the Zords....when Ivan took him out, shouldn't the Rangers have been *just fine?* Yet the *first thing* he says are "gone"... are **the Zords!**

In the film's reality, when the Ninjazords are "created", they stemmed directly from the "Great Power" which came from the planet Pheados, which the Ranger's accessed via the discipline of "Ninjetti" (imparted onto them by Dulcea, that planet's Master Warrior and implied to be an old ally of Zordon's.) These abilities were less "made", so much so as "ignited" within the Rangers, and when they found the Great Power source, it seemed to more "upgrade" their old powers; their suits, colors, basic weapons and abilities were *all* the same; even the Rangers' *helmets* kept their original Dino motif, *Despite* them now having new Animal spirits.  So the morphed forms, given to them by Zordon, seem to be "hard wired", with the only noticeable difference being the coins and increased ninja speed.

(Exactly *how* the Rangers are "more powerful" beyond the power of flight, is beyond me. I mean honestly, one would *Think* giant ancient creatures that could decimate forests would would be "more powerful" than a frog and a falcon, but, hey.... what do I know.)

So it's made pretty evident that  "The Power" is part of Zordon's legacy, and that would include the Zords. Concurrently, in the 2017 film, while it's not stated that Zordon "made" the coins, he **was shown to have TOTAL POWER over them,** even when dying, commanding them to lay dormant until they find worthy successors.

In terms of the Zords, Alpha himself stated that the Zords were built based on the most powerful creatures that existed at the time, the dinosaurs. But the implication *again* is that this was done "in house" with him and Zordon, not "outsourced" to some other powerful entity. Granted, these films take place almost *totally* outside the show's continuity (which makes sense in the 2017 film, but for the 95 film...not so much,) but, *again,* Alpha and Zordon are *stated* in season 2 to have created the white Rangers powers **from scratch,** with no outside input to be seen.

This is made even **more** convoluted in successive seasons, where we see Zords being everything from giant spirits ( *Power Rangers Lost Galaxy, Wild Force* ) to creations from ancient, advanced societies (Serpent Terror, *Power Rangers in Space*) to magical "avatar armor" or spirit forms, (*Mystic Force, Jungle Fury* ) to being (**somehow!**) *built by humans* (*Power Rangers Time Force, Light Speed Rescue, SPD, Ninja storm,* even by Tommy himself in *Dino Thunder.* ) So yes, obviously Zords *can* be constructed in numerous ways, even by humans, but...

**Is there any conclusive, canon proof as to who actually constructed the first Zords?**
I know there are a few Power Ranger comic book series which go deeper into the lore, and they *basically* follow and expand upon the canon of the original 1993 show. As such, information from there can be cited as well.

If we *have* to get a bit meta and go back to the first original Japanese Sentai Ranger series, we could do that too... but I'm specifically asking  about the Zordon Era of rangers and its possible offshoots.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I rather suspect you've already spent longer thinking about this than the creators of the show. At best, you're going to find a fan like you got a gig writing some tie-in fiction and tried to retcon an explanation.

Comment: @IMSoP Where is this "Fan"? Do not tease me with the possibility of their presence; please.....Take me to them.....

Comment: This questions has a large amount of extraneous information. If you edit it down, you may have a more approachable question which garners more (and better) answers.

Comment: @indigochild What exactly do you find extraneous? Keep in mind, Power Rangers is a _massive_ and **very long running** franchise, even if we _only_ stick to the American counterpart (almost 3 full decades). So there is a **lot** to cut through. The differences between information given in the _seasons,_ let alone between films, cn be contradictory; I didn't even touch upon the building of the "Turbo" Zords, full sentient machines which we **saw** Zordon and Alpha do. So before anyone should attempt an answer, better to give them as many facts to work with as possible.

Comment: @Russhiro The videos, the quotes, the exposition on various theories and why they don't work. Including some of that is helpful to show that you did your own research, but (IMO) there is too much detail to be effective.

Comment: @indigochild I couldn't be sure anyone attempting to answer would know all of the back details. It's true. I'd prefer greater numbers to see and widen the answer range, but it's also more useful to not have to sift through data I already have. So best to put it here in someway, so Stackmates know what _not_ to waste time looking for.